# Unable to send image via RabbitMQ C master

Tags: c, image, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-c

I am trying to send an image via RabbitMQ C master by using its binary data as message and then transferring it and copying it onto another image file.
My code is as follows:

**Client/sender:**

```
#include "amqp_wrapper_library.h"

int main(int argc, char const *const *argv)
{
  char const *hostname;
  int port;
  char const *exchange;
  char const *routingkey;
  char const *messagebody;
  char const *username;
  char const *password;
  amqp_connection_state_t conn;

  if (argc < 7) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: amqp_sendstring host port exchange routingkey messagebody username password\n");
    return 1;
  }

  hostname = argv[1];
  port = atoi(argv[2]);
  exchange = argv[3];
  routingkey = argv[4];
  username = argv[5];
  password = argv[6];

  int length;
  FILE *image1;
  image1= fopen("/home/sneha/Desktop/Sender/image1.jpg", "rb");    
  fseek(image1, 0, SEEK_END);         
  length= ftell(image1);           
  rewind(image1);               

  messagebody = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(length+1));
  fread(messagebody, length, 1, image1);
  printf("%s",messagebody);
  fclose(image1);

  conn = create_messagebus_context(hostname,port,username,password);
  send_message_on_messagebus(conn,exchange,routingkey,messagebody);
  close_messagebus_context(conn);

  return 0;
}
```

**Server/receiver:**

```
#include "amqp_wrapper_library.h"

int main(int argc, char const *const *argv)
{
  char const *hostname;
  int port;
  char const *exchange;
  char const *bindingkey;
  char const *username;
  char const *password;
  amqp_connection_state_t conn;
  FILE *image2;

  if (argc < 7) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: amqp_listen host port exchange bindingkey username password\n");
    return 1;
  }

  hostname = argv[1];
  port = atoi(argv[2]);
  exchange = argv[3];
  bindingkey = argv[4];
  username = argv[5];
  password = argv[6];

  conn = create_messagebus_context(hostname, port, username, password);
  image2 = fopen ("/home/sneha/Desktop/Receiver/image2.jpg", "wb");
  char *messagebody = receive_message_on_messagebus(conn,exchange,bindingkey);  
  fwrite (messagebody, 1, sizeof(messagebody), image2);
  printf("%s",messagebody);

  fclose(image2);

  close_messagebus_context(conn);

  return 0;
}
```

**amqp_wrapper_library.c**

```
#include "amqp_wrapper_library.h"

amqp_connection_state_t create_messagebus_context(char const *hostname,int port,char const *username,char const *password)
{
  amqp_socket_t *socket = NULL;
  amqp_connection_state_t conn = amqp_new_connection();
  socket = amqp_tcp_socket_new(conn);
  if (!socket) {
    die("creating TCP socket");
  }

  int status = amqp_socket_open(socket, hostname, port);
  if (status) {
    die("opening TCP socket");
  }

  die_on_amqp_error(amqp_login(conn, "/", 0, 131072, 0, AMQP_SASL_METHOD_PLAIN, username, password), "Logging in");
  amqp_channel_open(conn, 1);
  die_on_amqp_error(amqp_get_rpc_reply(conn), "Opening channel");
  return conn;
}

void close_messagebus_context(amqp_connection_state_t conn)
{
  die_on_amqp_error(amqp_channel_close(conn, 1, AMQP_REPLY_SUCCESS), "Closing channel");
  die_on_amqp_error(amqp_connection_close(conn, AMQP_REPLY_SUCCESS), "Closing connection");
  die_on_error(amqp_destroy_connection(conn), "Ending connection");
}

void send_message_on_messagebus(amqp_connection_state_t conn,char const *exchange,char const *routingkey,char const *messagebody)
{
    amqp_basic_properties_t props;
    props._flags = AMQP_BASIC_CONTENT_TYPE_FLAG | AMQP_BASIC_DELIVERY_MODE_FLAG;
    props.content_type = amqp_cstring_bytes("text/plain");
    props.delivery_mode = 2; /* persistent delivery mode */
    die_on_error(amqp_basic_publish(conn, 1, amqp_cstring_bytes(exchange), amqp_cstring_bytes(routingkey), 0, 0, &props, amqp_cstring_bytes(messagebody)), "Publishing");
}

char* receive_message_on_messagebus(amqp_connection_state_t conn,char const *exchange,char const *bindingkey)
{
  amqp_bytes_t queuename;
  {
    amqp_queue_declare_ok_t *r = amqp_queue_declare(conn, 1, amqp_empty_bytes, 0, 0, 0, 1, amqp_empty_table);
    die_on_amqp_error(amqp_get_rpc_reply(conn), "Declaring queue");
    queuename = amqp_bytes_malloc_dup(r->queue);
    if (queuename.bytes == NULL) 
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory while copying queue name");
      return 0;
    }
  }

  amqp_queue_bind(conn, 1, queuename, amqp_cstring_bytes(exchange), amqp_cstring_bytes(bindingkey), amqp_empty_table);
  die_on_amqp_error(amqp_get_rpc_reply(conn), "Binding queue");

  amqp_basic_consume(conn, 1, queuename, amqp_empty_bytes, 0, 1, 0, amqp_empty_table);
  die_on_amqp_error(amqp_get_rpc_reply(conn), "Consuming");

  {
    //for (;;) 
    //{
      amqp_rpc_reply_t res;
      amqp_envelope_t envelope;

      amqp_maybe_release_buffers(conn);

      res = amqp_consume_message(conn, &envelope, NULL, 0);

      if (AMQP_RESPONSE_NORMAL != res.reply_type) 
      {
        return;
      }
      char *result = (char *)malloc((int) envelope.message.body.len);
      sprintf(result,"%.*s",(int) envelope.message.body.len, (char *) envelope.message.body.bytes);
      amqp_destroy_envelope(&envelope);
      return result;
    //}
  }
}
```

However, the image2 is nt getting reconstructed. I checked image size, the sizes of both images do not match. What is the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

Data from a JPEG file is not a c-string (null-terminated string of bytes), thus functions like `printf` and `amqp_cstring_bytes` that expect a null-terminated strings cannot be used to handle the image data.

Instead of using a `const char*` to hold the jpg data, use an `amqp_bytes_t` struct in your code.

To read from a file into an `struct amqp_bytes_t`

```
amqp_bytes_t msg = amqp_bytes_alloc(length);
/* Make sure that allocation succeeded */
assert(msg.bytes != NULL);

fread(msg.bytes, msg.len, 1, image1);
...
/* Free the memory when you're done with it */
amqp_bytes_free(msg);
```

Do the reverse to write it back out:

```
/* if you wish to create a copy of the message body
 * free it using amqp_bytes_free */
amqp_bytes_t msg = amqp_bytes_malloc_dup(envelope.message.body);

fwrite(msg.bytes, msg.len, 1, image2);
```

Edit: add sample code.

Comment: but then how do i copy the amqp_bytes_t message onto the file? which format specifier should I use?

Comment: could you please explain more about the usage of amqp_bytes_t struct? while using it with amqp_cstring_bytes, how do i modify the code?